# rand() crashes my IDE

Tags: c++

Every time I use the value of n 7 or more, the code::blocks windows crashes and it gives me an error "all.exe has stopped working, windows is looking for a solution"

It's my first time using `rand()` so I am sure there are errors but I can't search for them because it compiles just fine.

```
int main()
{
    int n=0;
    int arr[n],i,j,temp;
    cout<<"How many numbers you want to enter:";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=rand()%30;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are writing code in C++, then you shouldn't be using `rand()`.

Comment: It's not rand crashing your IDE, it's the size zero array.

Comment: Try changing `n` to `1`. If it stops the crash, file a bug report at your IDE's bugzilla or whatever.

Comment: in `cin>>` make sure you enter number, and you might need to type cast it to int using `atoi`

Comment: You do `n=0`, then allocate, then read in `n`. Try allocating after reading `n`.

Comment: @Yashas I just searched for 'how to generate random numbers' :( what should I use?

Comment: There is a library `<random>` which comes with C++. It is safer and accurate. The `rand()` function doesn't easily allow you to generate uniform random numbers in a range without driving you nuts.

Comment: @Jatinder. Don't worry about that now. First understand the basics of your mistake, then find a better function.

Comment: The size of the array `arr` doesn't change as the value of `n` changes. The size of the array `arr` is what `n` was during declaration. By that, the size of your array `arr` will be `0` when you define it because `n` had the value `0` at that time. To allocate the array of correct size, you should first take input for `n` and then declare the array `arr`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I changed n to 20 but It still crashes. If I manually enter numbers, it works but as soon as I use the rand() loop block, it crashes if n is more than 6. If I use n 6 or less, it works just fine.

Comment: Try asking codeblocks not to scan your program.

Comment: @Yashas thank you, this worked. I didn't know how arrays worked. I asked for n before declaring arr[n] and it worked. Thank you and sorry for this stupid question lol.

Comment: @JatinderBrar That still doesn't explain why your IDE was crashing. You should file a bug report for your IDE.

Comment: @Jatinder. I have trouble believing you. Could you edit a version of the code where you set  `n=20` into the question?

Comment: @Jatinder. Consider deleting your question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think he can't because someone has posted an answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist This also crashes Codeblocks but if I request to enter n before I declare arr, it works. 



`int main()
{
    int n=20;
    int arr[n],i,j,temp;
    cout<<"How many numbers you want to enter:";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=rand()%1000;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}`

Comment: @Yashas. That answer has negative points. He can delete just fine.

Comment: That's probably because you type a number greater than 20

Comment: "Can't delete this as others have invested time etc. "

It's alright, let this comment stay here and provide amusement to other people :/

Comment: @MadPhysicist yeah lol, I understand now that you can't change array size by changing n  :(

Comment: @JatinderBrar -- `int n=0; int arr[n],i,j,temp;` -- Even if you set `n` to a value, declaring arrays using a variable to denote the number of entries is **not** valid C++.  I'm surprised no one has mentioned this so far.  The way dynamic arrays are done in standard C++ is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, I understand this now. Thanks

Comment: @MadPhysicist offtopic, where can I ask this kind of questions? I am just starting out in c++ so I will make a lot of stupid errors and ask a lot of stupid questions. Is there a branch of StackOverflow where we can ask stuff like this?

Comment: @Jatinder, I'm honestly not sure about that. However, an important part of learning programming, regardless of the language, is finding a good reference that works for you. Something like this should have been fixed by reading and research instead of asking a question in the first place. That intuition will come with time. Good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized n as 0. Because of which the array cant hold any elements

```
int main()
{
int n;
cout<<"How many numbers you want to enter:";
cin>>n;
int arr[n],i,j,temp;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    arr[i]=rand()%30;
    }
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: While what you pointed out is really an issue in the code, how do you know that it will solve the problem with the IDE? As it turns out in the comments, that isn't the cause for the IDE crashing.

Comment: I feel there is no problem in the IDE. It crashes only when there is a logical error in the code

Comment: IDEs are not supposed to crash when there is a logical error in the code. In fact, they should point the error out if possible.

Comment: IDE's  do not use any artificial intelligence to solve logical errors. Yes, they do handle some exceptions but not all of them.

Comment: @Yashas its clear that op's IDE isnt crashing, but rather his program (unless there is some IDE called all.exe I haven't heard of). He gives no indication of his IDE so we cannot answer a question about it. Also the fact that OP accepted this answer validates that.

Comment: @vinayak By the way, modern IDEs are sophisticated that they can see that and give a warning. If not, static analysis tools will definitely spot it.

Comment: @vinayak No mention that `arr[n]` is not valid C++?